# Dúvida sobre o método replace()

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, método

O método replace() é um método da classe str, correto?

Segue um código que 'roda' perfeitamente onde o objeto é um inteiro (ou pelo menos na minha interpretação). Ou no caso de interpolação isso muda?

Segue:

```
def moeda(valor, moeda = 'R$'):
    return f'{moeda}{valor:.2f}'.replace('.', ',')


velocidade = float(input('Qual é a velocidade do carro? (KM) '))
if velocidade > 80:
    print('VELOCIDADE PERMITIDA ULTRAPASSADA!')
    print('\033[1;31mMULTADO!\033[m')
    multa = (velocidade - 80) * 6
    multa = moeda(multa)
    print(f'Você foi multado em {multa}')
else:
    pass
```

PS. A função moeda() transforma um número inteiro para formato de moeda, substituindo os pontos de números inteiros por vírgulas.

Comment: é uma fstring, acho que ta normal, pois o numero é formatado dentro da string, e então a string é alterada pelo replace. acho que observar o ponto entre a string e o replace, isso em orientação a objeto indica que o replace vai agir na saida do metodo a frete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você mesmo disse, o `replace` é um método de strings e valores do tipo `int` ou `float` **não** o possuem.

O que ocorre no seu código é que você passa o valor para dentro de uma nova string utilizando a formatação de string [f-string](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/). Assim sendo, você está utilizando o método `replace` de uma `str` criada na formatação e não de um valor numérico. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
valor = 75.99
string_valor = f"R$ {valor}"

print(type(string_valor), "-", string_valor)  # <class 'str'> - R$ 75.99

string_valor = string_valor.replace(".", ",")
print(string_valor)
```

Comment: Perfeito Jean. Imaginei que fosse isso mesmo! F-Strings recebem tratamento de string. Obrigado!

Comment: Uma f-string na verdade, funciona como se fosse uma chamada de método - ela faz quase o mesmo que chamar `.format`, com os parâmetros apropriados, para a mesma string. - Inclusive, e isso é importante, ela só vai ter o valor final quando sua linha de código for executada. Strings normais já tem o valor final quando o arquivo for compilado para bytecode.